# Iterating through object in Hashmap

Tags: java, android

I need help trying to iterate through a Hashmap with objects. i got really stuck on how to do this. I tried checking on links like this  [How to iterate through objects in Hashmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21793275/how-to-iterate-through-objects-in-hashmap) but couldn't still implement it exactly as i want.

```
        List<Object> firstObject = new ArrayList<Object>();
        HashMap<Integer, Object> mapEx = new HashMap<> ();

        /* Put the data to Map*/

        mapEx.put(1, "First");       // String
        mapEx.put(2, 12.01);         // float
        mapEx.put(3, 12345);         // int
        mapEx.put(4, 600851475143L); // Long

        /* add map to firstObject */
        firstObject.add(mapEx);

        HashMap<String, Object> secondMap = new HashMap<> ();
        secondMap.put("mapEx", firstObject);

        Log.d("mapEx: ",secondMap.get("mapEx").toString()); 
        //When i print the line, this is the result below

        D/mapEx:﹕ [{4=600851475143, 1=First, 3=12345, 2=12.01}]
```

But How can i actually iterate through them? to come out this way.

```
4=600851475143
1=First
3=12345
2=12.01
```

and also maybe call each one by its key.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You mentioned **I can iterate through a simple Hashmaps**. `HashMap` contains objects only. So what you tried matter here more

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example you linked does answer the question. This how it would look like for your case :

```
for (Map.Entry<Integer, Object> entry : mapEx.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println(entry.getKey() + "=" + entry.getValue());
}
```

Also java 8 solution with streams

```
mapEx.entrySet().stream().forEach(e ->
    System.out.println(e.getKey() + "=" + e.getValue())
);
```

Tutorials about HashMaps [here](http://java67.blogspot.co.uk/2013/02/10-examples-of-hashmap-in-java-programming-tutorial.html) and [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html)

And for streams [here](http://winterbe.com/posts/2014/07/31/java8-stream-tutorial-examples/)

Comment: Thank you. Works....Please do have a detailed tutorial where i can learn about Hashmaps and using foreach efficiently? Please help me

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
for (HashMap<Object, Object> map : firstObject) {
    for (Object key : map.keySet()) {
        Object value = map.get(key);

        System.out.println("key = " + key + " value = " +  value);
    }
}
```